# Added DateTime? DataMemberto DataContract - existing clients fail with "Nullable object must have a value"

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, datetime, nullable

I want to add in some more DataMembers to the WCF DataContract, without breaking existing clients. This is why I added them as nullable DateTime objects, however the clients fail with "Nullable object must have a value".

I understand this is something to do with `DateTime? something = (DateTime?) null;`. How can I make this work without having to change all the existing clients?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
```

Comment: Thanks, figured this one out a couple of minutes ago too.